# How to make leaflet markers fit within sf polygons for any zoom level?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, r-sf, r-leaflet

**How can I dynamically size leaflet markers to fit within sf polygons for any zoom level?**

I have a series of sf polygons similiar to the nc (North Carolina) example below. Each of these polygons has its own respective marker. These markers should represent the polygon by fitting mostly inside the polygon and not overlapping with other markers.

*For Example:*

```
#install.packages("leaflet")
#install.packages("sf")

library(leaflet)
library(sf)

# load data from sf package
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) |>
  sf::st_transform("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

# subsetting for smaller map
nc <- nc[1:3,]

# markers will be placed at the lat/long centroid of the polygon
nc$centroid <- sf::st_centroid(nc$geometry)

# generating markers
icons <- leaflet::icons(
  iconUrl = c("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/985/985331.png",
              "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/985/985382.png",
              "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/985/985280.png"),
  iconWidth = 40, #sizing statically in pixels
  iconHeight = 40 #sizing statically in pixels
)

# Creating leaflet map with polygons and markers
leaflet() |>
  addPolygons(data = nc,
              fillOpacity = 1,
              fillColor = "white",
              color = "black",
              weight = 1) |>
  leaflet::addMarkers(data = nc$centroid,
                      icon = icons)
```

[image: Code Output]

I have tried scaling the markers based on the polygon area, but it is not proportional to the zoom scale.

**PROBLEM**

As the zoom changes, the markers either:

- become too small and fail to fill the polygon
- become too big, fail to fit within the polygon, and overlap with other markers

[image: Zoom In = Too Small]
[image: Zoom Out = Too Big]

**Is there a way to convert the current leaflet map size into pixels and then adjust the icons?**

Answer (score 1):

You can double size of markers on each zoom level, that would sort of 'bind' them to map view. You have to figure out size you want and you can use and set onZoom function like this:

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();

    //Update X and Y based on zoom level
    var x= 2; //for 0 level 
    var y= 2; //for 0 level
    for(var i = 0; i < currentZoom; i++){
        x *= 2;
        y *= 2;
    }     
    var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            iconSize:     [x, y] // Change icon size according to zoom level
        }
    });
    layer.setIcon(LeafIcon);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Svystun. However, I am looking for an implementation with the leaflet package in R rather than JavaScript.

Comment: How can I determine the JavaScript names of markers created in R? Then I could use htmlwidgets::onRender() to run the JavaScript code and return attributes of the markers not accessible in R?